# mongodb rendering from array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express

Let me rephrase my question.  How do I get the data which comes back in an array to render. (I am using handlebars)

The Code:

```
//http verbs
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res) {
      gm(req.url);
        app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); 

        //session check

        if (session checks out<-not actual code){

            //get mongoose data here
            var bmdata = bmquery.execFind(function(err, docs){
                console.log(docs);
                var model = {
                    layout:'blog.hbs',
                    BlogModel: docs,
                };
            //render page
            res.render('blog', model);
            });
        }

        else {
            console.log('illegal user');
            console.log('redirection in progress');
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    }

};
```

The console.log of docs comes back in an array like so:
[{document 1},{document 2}]

Could you also do this dynamically so that I do not have to put the array position.

My handlebars looks like this:

```
{{BlogModel[0].title}}
{{BlogModel[0].content}}
{{BlogModel[1].title}}
{{BlogModel[1].content}}
```

**The Problem**
Data comes back in an array and I cant get it to render out dynamically or at all.

Comment: You would be better studying JavaScript more throughly. Seems you don't know scope and async nature of JavaScript.
Also you should read documentation of http://expressjs.com throughly.

Comment: Yea Sorry I phrased that poorly, I fixed it.  Yes I know what a scope is and was previously asking if I could pass the generated variable from in the scope to out of it.  (which I cant)  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var BlogModel = mongoose.model('blogmodel', BlogPost, 'blogmodel');
var bms = BlogModel.find({ "date" : { $gte : new Date("2011-01-01T00:00:00Z")}} ).limit(1);

module.exports = {
   get: function(req, res) {
      //ExecFind is asnychornous, so you need to wait to get the data to render it.
      bms.execFind(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        var model = {
             layout:'blog.hbs',
             BlogModel: docs
        };
        res.render('blog', model);
      });
   }
};
```

Also, this should be on your configuration of the app, not stranded on a module in the app

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

And as someone say, you should learn how to handle the asyn nature of node and understand a little bit more the concept of callbacks.

Comment: I updated my code, It works if inside of my model variable I have docs[0] or 1 but it will not load more than one array value at once and I want it to load around 5.

Comment: .limit(1); <- That. Change it to 5